# C++ Builder allows String Comparison with Int - why?

Tags: c++, string, c++builder

I recently started working on an old solution built using C++Builder (Borland).

I ran into code that allows some unexpected operations.

1) assignment of int to String with no conversion:

```
String x = 12; //this works... I would expect a type mismatch..
```

2) Comparison of String to int with no issue:

```
String s = "12";
int x = 12;
bool b = s == x; // Again... I expect an error..
```

Does C++Builder do some automatic conversion?
Is there a list of "OMG I can't believe they do this" for C++Builder?

Comment: What is `String`?  It is not a standard C++ type.

Comment: The Borland "standard" string classes (not to be confused with the C++ standard `std::string` class) typically allows implicit conversion from integer types, as they have non-explicit constructors for that.

Comment: IMO, many questions about C++Builder tend to use C++Builder and Delphi specific types. I wouldn't use the general C++ tag, just the C++Builder tag. Then such questions wouldn't arise. This is a question about C++Builder's String, so not a general C++ question anyway.

Answer (score 7):

This is the Borland C++ Builder String (not the `std::string` of Standard C++).

It is made that way to allow you to create almost all kinds of strings, as [this Borland C++ Builder Strings reference](http://www.functionx.com/bcb/topics/strings.htm) mentions:

> The AnsiString class provides a lot of constructors that allow you to
>   create a string of any kind. For example you can use it to declare:
>
> An integer:
>
> ```
> AnsiString Int = 120;
> ```

As RemyLebeau said: Note that `String` is not an actual type, it is an alias for either `AnsiString` (C++Builder 2007 and earlier) or `UnicodeString` (C++Builder 2009 and later). Both do implement implicit conversions from numeric types.

Answer (score 1):

This is [just how it was made](http://www.functionx.com/bcb/topics/strings.htm).

Common wisdom is not to permit implicit conversions between strings and other types like this, but this stuff is pretty old and probably wouldn't be made like this nowadays.

I would advise sticking to standard types where possible.

Comment: … except that `std::string` also “allows” this ;-) — and segfaults. The Borland behaviour isn’t great but it’s a thousand times more sensible than the standard class behaviour.

Comment: @Konrad: Does it? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9912e15f2ecada62 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24b953322fcce7e7

Comment: Try `std::string str = 0; std::cout << str;` … but you knew already that that’s what I meant, didn’t you?

Comment: @KonradRudolph The null pointer literal is a breaking case, yes. But it's not generally so for integers, and not for the integer being asked about in the question. And no I didn't know already that's what you meant, because you didn't say it!

Comment: Fair enough. I’d have thought the quotes, smiley, and reference to segfault were enough of a clue.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I did think it was an odd comment coming from a knowledgeable lad like yourself  Perhaps I should have put 2 and 2 together (to get 0); I blame its being Friday

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "*this stuff is pretty old and probably wouldn't be made like this nowadays*" - in the latest version of C++Builder, its Delphi-compatible `String` classes (`AnsiString`, `UnicodeString`, and `WideString`) DO still support implicit conversions from various numeric types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But those _are_ exactly these types that we're already talking about that have existed since antiquity. Once a thing exists, there are further issues with changing how it works in future versions of that same thing. But if you were to create a string type from scratch now you probably wouldn't incorporate such implicit conversions.